# Banach Tarski, Axiom of Choice and non-measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, axiom-of-choice, paradoxes

I had a question about the link between Banach Tarski paradox, Axiom of Choice and non-measurable sets. I know that the construction of sphere decomposition in the Banach Tarski context is made by the following : we take an arbitrary point and then rotate the sphere north, south, west and east to access to countably many other points that are given a coordinate such as NWSENNES and separate in 4 sets the words starting with N, the ones with W, S and E. Since, this does not reach all the points, we repeat the process for a new origin. We do it again and again and the only way to do it is to use axiom of choice so are there uncountably many origins ? I also know that every countable set (such as the words starting with N) has measure zero. Using additivity, I am tempted to say that this construction has also measure zero then. But additivity works only for countable number of sets, so I guess that the construction is made of uncountably many countable disjoint sets. I still do not understand how can a union of sets of measure zero be a non-measurable set...

Comment: It's only 5 pieces, not uncountably many. The issue is that the pieces are non-measurable. The existence of non-measurable sets is given by AC. Also, given any non-measurable set $X$, The uncountable union $$\bigcup\limits_{x\in X}\{x\}=X$$is such that each set has measure 0.

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected my question a few seconds ago @DonThousand

Comment: It's still incorrect; you talk about 'the construction of sphere decomposition is made of (uncountably many?) countable disjoint sets.' It is in fact made up of finitely many uncountable sets.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In fact I am not very clear about it, I am talking about the construction we are making in the proof, the one that consists of choosing an origin rotating the sphere north, south, west and east, writing coordinates, repeating with new origin, etc... I'll edit my question

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I hope it is better now

Comment: @Kilkik I gave an example of a union of measure 0 sets not being a measure 0 set.

Comment: @DonThousand you said that X was non-measurable so its not a measure 0 set ?

Comment: "I still do not understand how can a union of sets of measure zero be a non-measurable set..." Every set, measurable or non-measurable, is a union of one-element sets, which are measure zero sets.